# Small historical stone bridge in the North of Seoul

Tags: where-on-earth, south-korea, landmarks

I want to go to this semi-famous historical bridge in 수성동 계곡 (Suseong-dong Gyegok, "Suseong Stream Valley") at 기린교 (Girin-gyo, "Giraffe Bridge") but I don't know its latitude/longitude:

[image: bridge]

It is in the North of Seoul and historical details are described by this blog article: http://blog.naver.com/kissmenet/220155477289

Painters have taken it as a model in their paintings, and famous people crossed it. I am not sure whether it has a name, but most people have seen it.

What is its latitude/longitude?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Name: Inwangsan Suseong-dong Valley

Address:

> 서울특별시 종로구 옥인동 185-3
>
> 185-3 Ogin-dong Jongno-gu, Seoul, Korea

Location: [Google Maps](https://www.google.com.sa/maps/place/Ogin-dong,+Jongno-gu,+Seoul,+South+Korea/@37.5823652,126.9627349,215m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x357ca2bd27fd1e55:0xce9371d4dc7b2814?hl=en)

Sources: [TheSeoulStop.com](http://www.theseoulstop.com/hiking/suseong-dong-valley.html), [TheSoulOfSeoul.com](http://thesoulofseoul.net/2014/08/21/a-landscape-revealed/)

The map is not too clear to determine the exact location of the bridge, this is as close as it gets.

Comment: I can't stop reading it as sausage-dong..